# html file + d3.js script file + input data manually in html file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am new in d3.js language. I am trying to built a simple application but I stuck some where. I have a separate `.js` file `jack.js` which makes pie chart when you link it with html page.

**Problem** I want to use that file in every html page with different data. But i cant find the perfect solution of this. whenever page loaded in browser, file load its pie chart visualization. So can you suggest me what should i need to do?

HTML page

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3: Pie layout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/pie.js"></script>
    <script>
      dataset = [1,2,3,4,5];
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>                                          `
```

jack.js

```
//Width and height
var w = 300;
var h = 300;
var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];

var outerRadius = w / 2;
var innerRadius = 0;
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var pie = d3.layout.pie();

//Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
var color = d3.scale.category10();

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

//Set up groups
var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

//Draw arc paths
arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", arc);

//Labels
arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });
```

Comment: Wrap the code in `Jack.js` into a function accepting a parameter named `dataset`. Source it, and call it with different data from where ever you want passing in the data.

Comment: @Mark hi thanks for reply. i got your point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/pie.js"></script>
<script>dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];</script>
</body>
```

This way you can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Remove `var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];` from jack.js and put them either in your html file like you did in the head of your html file. Call jack.js in the body.

This will ensure that the data is loaded first before jack.js.

Hence your code will look like this

### Html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3: Pie layout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/pie.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### pie.js

```
        var w = 300;
        var h = 300;


        var outerRadius = w / 2;
        var innerRadius = 0;
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie();

        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        //Set up groups
        var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                      .data(pie(dataset))
                      .enter()
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("class", "arc")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

        //Draw arc paths
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc);

        //Labels
        arcs.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });
```

Alternatively, you place wrap you d3 code in a `$( document ).ready( //your d3 code here )` http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

### Alternatively

#### pie.js

```
$( document ).ready(
        // d3 code here
        var pie = d3.layout.pie();

        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
        var color = d3.scale.category10();
        ....
)
```